Shortcut to display the table of content of a pdf with mupdf
I cannot find a way / keyboard shortcut to display the table of content in mupdf, although I am pretty sure I could do that on my previous system (I was on MacOS and now I am on Ubuntu 22.04).
I did not find this information in the man page
Is there a way to do it?

The shortcut is: o (the letter) when using mupdf-gl (does not work with plain mupdf)
